# Android : Problems with separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

I'm working on a project which uses the device's mic to get the Amplitude. This is done using a separate thread from the UI (main) thread. The thread updates a global variable (*amp*) and once a simple button is pressed, the Log is outputted, displaying the global variable.

The problem is that 9 times out of 10 the output is 0.0, sometimes it gets to the numbers it is expected (100s or 1000s), depending on the sound being captured, but this is totally random. I can't figure out what exactly is happening.

This is my code:

```
package com.example.mark.sound_test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SoundMeter s = new SoundMeter();
    Button listen;
    double amp;
    TextView textView;

    public void updateAmp(double n)  //updates global variable with input
    {
        amp = n;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listen);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {  //new Thread which listens to amplitude
            public void run()
            {
                s.start();
                double tmp;
                while(true) {
                    tmp = s.getAmplitude();
                    updateAmp(tmp); //update global variable with new amplitude
                }
            }
        }).start();

        listen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Log.i("myapp","Amplitude:"+amp); //display amplitude on button click
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the output that I have been getting (in a loud environment):

[image: Output]

As per request:

Code for SoundMeter :

```
package com.example.mark.sound_test;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SoundMeter {

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    public void start() {
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                return;
            }
            mRecorder.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
            return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        else
            return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Try displaying loging value in thread which listens

Comment: Post `SoundMeter`.

Comment: I think you are trying to log the amplitude when you click a UI button. It would be more helpful if you can create a `HandlerThread` to log as it will remove errors due to manual intervention.

Comment: Try to designate amp as volatile: `volatile double amp;`. Does it help?

Comment: @PravinSonawane would you kindly specify more on how to do that?

Comment: @Vasiliy tried that - nothing noticeable has changed unfortunately.

Comment: It was the only (though not probable) thing that could be related to multi-threading (IMHO). I guess your issue is not multithreading, but MediaRecorder returning 0 for getMaxAmplitude. Consider changing question's title in order to attract relevant people. Also, there are several more questions related to getMaxAmplitude returning 0 values

Comment: @Logan You can get information about HandlerThread here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html Alternatively, can you simply log inside the `while(true)` loop of the thread to remove the possibility of a multithreading issue?

Comment: please explain thoroughly what you want to achieve. When you press the button, what do you expect to log? the amplitude at that specific time? the amplitude peak of the last second? or something else?